# JQuery AJAX HandleErrorAtribute PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I have a function that submits a form to a MVC controller as follows -

```
function submitForm() {
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Users/Index',
                data: $('#searchForm').serialize(),
                beforeSend: function() { 
                    $('.usersearchresult').fadeOut('fast', function () { $('.loadinggif').show(); }); 
                    },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('.loadinggif').hide();
                    $('.usersearchresult').hide().html(response).fadeIn('normal');   
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                $('.loadinggif').hide();
                $('.usersearchresult').hide().html(response).fadeIn('normal');   
            }
            });

            return false;
        }
```

I wanted a central location to catch errors so I have extended `HandleErrorAttribute` -

```
public class ClientExceptionAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext  context)
    {
        Log.Error(context.Exception);

        context.ExceptionHandled = true;

        // Verify if AJAX request
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            // Use partial view in case of AJAX request
            var result = new PartialViewResult();
            result.ViewName = "~/views/shared/error.ascx";
            context.Result = result;
        }
    }
}
```

The error view is very simple -

```
@model String

@{
    Layout = null;
}


<div class="exception">
    <img src="../Content/Graphics/warning.png" />
    <br />
    <div class="message">@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model) ? "User Entry Api is currently unavailable" : Model) </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that AJAX on error never renders the partial view (error.cshtml) - it just gives me a blank screen.

So I have two questions -

1. How do I make AJAX render the partial error view
2. How can I pass a model to a partial view in the `ClientExceptionAttribute`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result.ViewName = "~/views/shared/error.ascx";` should be `result.ViewName = "Error";`

If anyone knows the answer to question number two I'd appreciate it.